# Не добавляется текст в поле

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-constraintlayout

Работаю в android studio,создал constraintlayout, теперь не понимаю почему за его границы не добавляется ничего, ни текст, ни кнопки. Ума не приложу, где накосячил.

Привожу картинку, в это место не добавляется абсолютно ничего :
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDv3w.png]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="65dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/mainwid"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/znak"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/mainwid"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="52dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/znak"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_help" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/con"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="145dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:rotation="270"
            android:text="@string/main"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView3"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mesa"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="145dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="52dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:rotation="270"
            android:text="@string/about"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/con"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nas"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="145dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="108dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:rotation="270"
            android:text="@string/con"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/mesa"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />



</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас жёстко задана ширина корневого контейнера:

```xml
android:layout_width="65dp"
```

Соответственно за пределы контейнера ничего вставить нельзя.
Так контейнер займёт всю ширину экрана:

```xml
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```